# how do I stop a script only for IE 8

Tags: javascript, html

I have to stop below mentioned javascript file on IE8 and 7. When I removed the 'responsive-nav.js' responsive navigation is not working on IE higher versions. So anybody please advise to stop its working on IE8 and 7.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to stop it?  Why not spend your time figuring out how to make it work correctly?

Comment: There is a great script called http://yepnopejs.com/ that is designed for exactly this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--[if !IE 8]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This is called a conditional statement. The "!" before "IE" indicates *"not"* therefore the statement is saying: If this browser is NOT IE run this script.

You also can target a specific version of IE like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a downlevel-reveal conditional comment:

```
<![if IE gt 8]><script ...></script><![endif]>
```

Note however that use of such a comment will cause your page to fail validation due to "unknown tags".

Answer (score 0):

[HTML conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if !((IE 7)||(IE 8))]--> <script>...</script> <!--[endif]-->
```